# Spring Tool Suite Remote Debug will disable the TCP to the port

Tags: java, eclipse, weblogic, spring-tool-suite

I am trying to remote debug java application hosted in Weblogic 12c locally using Spring Tool Suite. But when I tried to debug from STS I am getting `Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused. Connection refused: connect` error message.
I tried debugging my local server from outside PC in same network and got success. So I am thinking my STS or PC has some issue on accessing the port.
What I noticed is at the time I start Weblogic I can get `TcpTestSucceeded : True` to the debug port using PowerShell `Test-NetConnection -ComputerName <IP> -Port <port>` command. But once I debug Remote Application using STS I will get `TcpTestSucceeded : False` for above command in PowerShell. Can help me to get understand why STS debug disable the port?